# error in sqlite3_exe()

Tags: iphone

sir i have working with db connectivity i have written all code and i imported the header file also.but its showing the error in the line of sqlite3_exe symbol not found in architecture

help me to clear...!!!!

```
 NSFileManager *filemgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO)
{
    const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errorMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE NUMERIC)";
        if (sqlite3_exe(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL,NULL, &errorMsg)!=SQLITE_OK)
        {
            status.text=@"Failed to crate table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }else {
        status.text=@"Faild to open/create database";
    }
}
```

the error line is

```
if (sqlite3_exe(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL,NULL, &errorMsg)!=SQLITE_OK)
```

warning is the implicit declaration of function "sqlite3_exe" is invalid in c99.
error is Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
 "_sqlite3_exe", referenced from:
  -[DatabaseViewController viewDidLoad] in DatabaseViewController.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sqlite3_exec. Not sqlite3_exe.
Please check.
"C" is missing in exe.

Comment: but its its not store the values

Comment: After running this code, Please check the created sqlite database in application documents directory. and check if the table created.

Comment: :i have no idea about making call in i phone with programmatically so please help me to write a code .

requirements i need 2buttons if i press the 1st button call should be go for the particular number then if i press the2nd button call should be ended...

can any one give me the code please.....?

Comment: First of all, You cant make call in your application. Instead of this you can make a call to specified number using openURL method of UIApplication class. Once you call this URl. Your application will get into background & iOS calling application will open. So you can't end call in your application, but can initiate it using button.

Comment: yeah sir got it.one more i need to write recording app. same like two button if i press 1st one voice should be record and second stop and play button should be there if i click the play button it should play. help me i have no idea about it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for the same. You can record the audio here. you can

```
#define DOCUMENTS_FOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]

    - (void) startRecording{

    UIBarButtonItem *stopButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Stop" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(stopRecording)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = stopButton;
    [stopButton release];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    err = nil;
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

    recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];



    // Create a new dated file
    NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    NSString *caldate = [now description];
    recorderFilePath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER, caldate] retain];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
    err = nil;
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    if(!recorder){
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [err localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }

    //prepare to record
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
    if (! audioHWAvailable) {
        UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cantRecordAlert show];
        [cantRecordAlert release]; 
        return;
    }

    // start recording
    [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 10];

    }

    - (void) stopRecording{

    [recorder stop];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: recorderFilePath];
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url path] options: 0 error:&err];
    if(!audioData)
        NSLog(@"audio data: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    [editedObject setValue:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] forKey:editedFieldKey];   

    //[recorder deleteRecording];


    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    err = nil;
    [fm removeItemAtPath:[url path] error:&err];
    if(err)
        NSLog(@"File Manager: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);



    UIBarButtonItem *startButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Record" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(startRecording)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = startButton;
    [startButton release];

    }

    - (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *) aRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
    {

    NSLog (@"audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:");
    // your actions here

    }
```

For Playing You can use these lines in stop recording method:

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                               pathForResource:@"click"
                                               ofType:@"caf"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    [click play];
    [click release];
```

Make sure you are passing the correct URL of the recorded sound path into the app. And these lines will play them for you in audio player.

Comment: Need to check it. You can try putting your key and check. Hope it works.

Comment: Follow these 2 links. "01:" http://sree.cc/iphone/record-audio-in-iphone   "02:"  http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/recording-iphone-audio/225900126?pgno=1

Comment: :sir in that coe some eror is there.the error is i++...                     recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Myrecording%d.%@",i++, @"caf"]]];

Comment: This is for your recorded file name with path.

Comment: but its showing error like "variable i is uninitialized when used here" how to clear...